# How to use accessor function

Tags: php, function, class, attributes, accessor

I've read that you can make all your access through a single section of code using accessor function. The book shows me the code, I got it.

But I don't know how to use it. Can someone give me an example or a syntax to use this function please?

The code from my book:

```
class classname
{
    public $attribute;
    function __get($name)
    {
        return $this->$name;
    }
    function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->$name = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the part that you're having difficulty with? If you call a property (*any* property), `__set` will set the property `$name` to `$value`, and `__get` gets the value. For example in `$foo->number = 42` `number` will be `$name`, and `42` will be `$value`.

Comment: He's just curious, that's all.

Comment: And actually, there's a significance. you can't access private variables without __set and __get. although you can also create dynamic variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessors provide a way to access private class variables.

An example(let's just say that `$attribute` is private):

```
<?php 
     $classNameObject = new classname();

     // Setting the value
     $classNameObject->attribute = "A value";

     // Getting the value
     echo $classNameObject->attribute;
?>
```

But in php the `__set()` and `__get()` functions work in a way that they can create dynamic properties.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted ^_^ Thank you!

Comment: I got this error: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Apache24\htdocs\test3.php on line 17, any idea why?

<?php
 class classname
 {
  public $attribute;
  function __get($name)
  {
   return $this->$name;
  }
  function __set($name, $value)
  {
   $this->$name = $value;
  }
 }
 
 $a = new classname();
 $a = "A value";
 echo $a->attribute;
?>

Comment: Note `$a = "A value"`. You changed $a from being a `classname` object into a `String` object. php has a dynamic variable typing.